# How to make interactive Bokeh Histograms?

Tags: bokeh

I have been working with `bokeh` for a little while now and when showing people data they really seem to love being able to interact with the data. I've managed to acheive this via `bokeh serve`, but only for scatter diagrams. Can this be done with histograms?

The problem, I think, is that as a high-level chart, `Histogram()` won't take a `ColumnDataSource` as its argument, which seems to be what the interactivity is based around. I'm not very clued up about this, so any help or comment on workarounds is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I fairly new to Bokeh as well - so there may be a better way, but my quick work around was to create my histogram with multiple rectangle glyphs. The only catch is that rect uses the y value passed to it as the center of the glyph, rather than its absolute height.

Something like:

plot.rect(x, y=bar_height/2, width = 1, height = bar_height, source= source_data)

Works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It wasn't really doing the job for me so I switched to Crossfiler.js and Graphs.js. I'll probably go back to looking at Bokeh in the future when it's moved on a bit.